# TVOS - App Icon must have at least 2 layers with applicable content issue

Tags: ios, xcode, tvos

I am trying to archive my TVOS app, but I keep getting the following error:

```
The image stack "App Icon" must have at least 2 layers with applicable
content. Although it has 2 layers, none have applicable content.
```

This makes no sense because I have everything that the documentation asks for.

I have two layers, Front, which has an Icon at 1x and at 2x and is a .png (400px x 240px for 1x).

Then I have Back, which follows the same structure but is a JPEG.

Can anyone assist here? I have been struggling with this for days.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72820730/294884

Answer (score 0):

Both of your layers need to .png files.  You cannot use jpeg files.

From the [Apple Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/tvos/icons-and-images/app-icon/)

[image]

Comment: Can you obtain some other PNG files and try to create an icon as a test;  There may be something wrong with one or both of your files.  If you have two working files then you can substitute in your files one at a time to see which is causing the problem.

Comment: I took the samples directly off the Apple site. I think I should just remove everything and start again.

Comment: @LukeVenter the sizes are ultra-fussy, and change all the time: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72820730/294884